# MySQL - Fetch date without timezone offset

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, date, timezone-offset

I'm storing Date of bith (DOB) as Date column in mySQL table.

Here's the problem now:
When I insert the date-of-bith, eg: 2001/02/02, I'm able to store it without any problem.
But when I select it (`SELECT dob FROM table1`), I'm getting result in UTC format like: `2001-02-01T18:30:00.000Z`

I went on further digging to find out it's because of UTC offset.

Is there any way to return Date as stored in table without UTC offset? Date of birth(s) needs to be constant for all timezone irrespective of UTC.

Note: I don't want to change Server timezone since I do have certain column that uses time difference.

**Edit: When I execute the query using MySQL workbench, I'm getting expected results but when I use node (mysqljs), I'm getting results in timezone format.**

**Edit: Just found out that it was a problem with mysqljs since it connects to mysql server using timezone property. (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#connection-options)**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this mean that dob is a type datetime and not date? How did time get included in the output? If this is some mysterious (to me) symptom of a date column, can you edit your question to include a link from your "further digging", please? I'm curious.

Comment: @UncleCarl No. DOB is a date column.

Comment: Plus setting dateStrings: true served my puprose => "Force date types (TIMESTAMP, DATETIME, DATE) to be returned as strings..."
it retuned the date time unchanged in some default format

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So, It was an issue with mysqljs and I used `timezone` option while creating connection. mysqljs uses `local` as default for `timezone` option and setting it to `Z` seems to fix the issue for me.

Here's a sample:

```
`mysql.createPool({
  connectionLimit: mySQLConfig.connectionLimit,
  host: mySQLConfig.host,
  user: mySQLConfig.username,
  password: mySQLConfig.password,
  database: mySQLConfig.database,
  timezone: 'Z'
});`
```

Answer (score 3):

You might try setting `dateStrings` to `true` in your mysqljs connection parameters. The issue here is that mysqljs is converting it to a javascript date object. This will make it return as a string with your expected data.

Comment: Yes. It was a problem with mysqljs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just to ignore the timezone use [MySQL `date`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date):

```
select date(dob) from table1
```

but result will be `'yyyy-mm-dd'`

If you want it to be formatted like `2001/02/02`:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(dob,'%y/%m/%d') from table1
```

Comment: No luck. What's even more surprising is that when I execute the query using mySQL workbench, I get the actual result without any problem. But when I use node (mysqljs), I'm getting result in UTC timezone.

Answer (score 1):

First, This not an error. mysql npm do this to avoid time conflicting over difference time zones. But when we are working locally this is bit disgusting.

To avoid this you can add a connection option called, 'timezone' and set it to 'local' or 'Z'

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host     : 'example.org',
    user     : 'bob',
    password : 'secret',
    timezone : 'local'
});
```

Reference :- [mysql npm doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#date)